# Phalcon unable to find class

Tags: php, namespaces, phalcon, phalcon-routing

Hello all im trying to load multiple libraries which is in different folders in library folder using namespaces but i keep getting not found

My directory structure is like this

```
app/
   controllers/
   models/       
   library/
   views/
```

My loader.php is like this

```
$loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();

/**
 * We're a registering a set of directories taken from the configuration file
 */

$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Test\Name'        => __DIR__ . "/../library/",
));

$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        $config->application->controllersDir,       
        $config->application->modelsDir
    )
)->register();
```

And my basecontroller is trying to call like this

```
$var = new Test\Name\functions();
```

and btw the file functions in library is like this

```
class functions extends Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component
{


    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
    }

    public function checking(){

        echo 'checks';

    }

}
```

i Keep getting

```
Fatal error: Class 'Test\Name\functions' not found in C:\wamp\www\app\controllers\ControllerBase.php on line 38
```

Any help is appreciated guys thnx

Answer (score 1):

I think that your class should have:

```
namespace Test\Name;

class functions extends Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component
{
// ...  rest of it
```

on top.

I would also make this configuration:

```
$loader->registerDirs(
    array(
        $config->application->controllersDir,       
        $config->application->modelsDir,
        __DIR__ . "/../library/",
    )
)->register();
```

So your class would be in (also I would rename your class to Functions:

```
app/library/Test/Name/Functions.php
```

So it would be obvious that your `Functions` class is in `Test\Name` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Having trouble finding the discussion that clued me in but, my understanding is that when using namespaces, you use namespaces. When using directories and other rules, you don't use namespaces.

Namespaces are faster so probably best to just stick with them, dropping the `registerDirs` as they are superfluous and mean the same thing as the namespaces:

```
library\Test\Name.php
```

becomes:

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Apps\Module\Controllers'   => $config->application->controllersDir,
    'Apps\Module\Models'        => $config->application->modelsDir,
    'Test'        => __DIR__ . "/../library/Test",
));
```

Then available as `Test\Name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'App'        => __DIR__ . "/../library/",
), true);
```

it will merge all sub dir, if you librarry dir architecture like this

library
 - Test
   - Name.php

You can call new \App\Test\Name();